# How to Deploy an App Service in azure with Laravel 8 and PHP 8 without public endpoint?

Tags: php, laravel, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

I am Deploying an App Service in azure with Laravel 8 and PHP 8 but i am unable to remove /public from URL.

Generally we solve this problem with

1. Directing Domain to public folder and .htaccess/web.config file in public folder
2. placing an htaccess/web.config file in root

but here it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am answering this question for future users as i spent apprx 7-8 hours in fixing it.

I took help from [schaako.de](https://www.schakko.de/2021/09/08/deploying-php-8-0-applications-with-azure-app-service/) , [cristopher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/comments/579045/view.html) and [azureossd](https://azureossd.github.io/2021/09/02/php-8-rewrite-rule/index.html) and writing it here.

**Open SSH**

Navigate to your `App Service` via the `Azure Portal`. Under the `Development Tools section`, select `SSH` .

**Default site config**

copy of the existing configuration and place the file inside the `/home/site` directory using this commands

```
cp /etc/nginx/sites-available/default /home/site/default
```

Now edit the `/home/site/default` file and update as described in [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/deployment#server-configuration) Server Configuration settings

```
location / {
    index  index.php index.html index.htm hostingstart.html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

**custom startup script**

You will now need to create a custom startup script and save the file as `/home/site/startupscriptbymoon.sh`

Add following commands in above file

```
cp /home/site/default /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
service nginx reload
```

**Startup Command and Test**

Now navigate back to your `App Service` via the `Azure Portal`. Under the `Settings section`, select `Configuration` and then `General Settings`.

In `Startup Command` text box enter the following:

```
/home/site/startupscriptbymoon.sh
```

navigate back to your application and reload.
enjoy!

Comment: You are the BOSS.....................

Answer (score 1):

I went through the same struggle and blogged my findings at my blog https://www.azurephp.dev/2021/09/php-8-on-azure-app-service/.

The move to Linux only containers and from Apache to Nginx added a whole series of troubles which I reported in my article. Check it out for more details.